# heap sort, everything but the first two values are sorted

Tags: c++

Edit:
It now works all but the first two numbers only this time the number in the [1] index should be swapped with the one in the [0] index. However, whenever I go to do that my program crashes...
Original: 
For one of my projects I'm having to time different sorting algorithms and so far I've gotten them all to work but my heap sort. Everything seems to work fine but when I output the sorted array, the first two values are jumbled and I can't seem to find out why.

```
void heapify(int* array, int index, int size)
{
  int j, temp;
  temp = array[index];
  j = (2 * index);

  while (j <= size)
  {
     if (j < size && array[j + 1] > array[j])
          j = (j + 1);

     if (temp > array[j])
          break;
     else if (temp <= array[j])
     {
          array[(j / 2)] = array[j];
          j = (2 * j);
     }
  }

 array[(j / 2)] = temp;
 return;
}

void buildHeap(int* array, int size)
{
  int i;

  for (i = (size / 2); i >= 1; i--)
  {
      heapify(array, i, size);
  }
}

double heapsort(int* array, int size)
{
  int i;
  clock_t end, begin;

  begin = clock(); //Start the timer//
  buildHeap(array, size);

  for (i = size; i >= 2; i--)
  {
      swap(array[i], array[1]);
      heapify(array, 1, (i - 1));
  }
  end = clock(); //Stop the timer//

  return diffClocks(end, begin); //Return the amount of time it took to sort//
}
```

Unfortunately, the array is randomly generated inside a main() that is given to us and changes every time it's ran but a sample of the output is:
13, 
-33686019, 
0,
0, 
1, 
2, 
3, 
. . . (everything from here on is sorted)

Answer (score 0):

```
//in heapsort() function
for (i = size; i >= 2; i--)
{
      swap(array[i], array[1]);
      heapify(array, 1, (i - 1));
}

//in buildHeap() function
heapify(array, i, size);
```

This code block will give you a problem(assuming you are passing the actual size of the array to the `heapsort()` function) because when you say `array[i]`, initially `i=size` and since array indexing starts from **0**,the maximum index is **size-1** and `array[i]` gives you a garbage data. So use `i=size-1` in `heapsort()` function and `heapify(array, i, size-1)` in `buildHeap()` function.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't see that. That did fix the huge number but I still have one like the 13 above that is still in front of the sorted part that I can't find where it's coming from.

Comment: @Jab2ak Its is probably coming from the logic of your sort algorithm(not including the first array element,**array[0]**, in the sort). You should check it again carefully.